# Proper protocol for saying Mi Sheberach for the ill

Tags: tefilla, choleh-sick

I've seen different shuls do different methods of saying Mi Shebreach for the ill. Methods I have seen:

- Chazzan (or gabbai) says the intro aloud; people line up and give him the name and he says them aloud
- Same as above except that he reads off a printed list or a stack of cards / notes rather than people lining up. Those who are in the cong. who did not have their name submitted don't line up to announce the name, but say the name to themselves, silently.
- Chazzan says the intro then pauses. He will read names from the list silently and others who have not submitted names will say their names silently. Then, he concludes the end of the blessing aloud

I've also seen some cong. say separate prayers for males and females while others place them together. Does this matter? Is there a preferred method?

I am curious if there is any specific protocol mentioned in Shulchan Aruch or elsewhere. Or, is any method fine?

Comment: My weekday minyan does 2 followed by 1 -- the chazzan reads the printed list and then people have a chance to add to it out loud.  (People don't line up somewhere; they just call out the names from their seats as the chazzan scans the room.)

Comment: BTW: The halacha is that on Shabbat one may not pray for a person unless he deathly ill. I.e. that one would be allowed to transgress Shabbat for them. That would shrink a lot of lists.

Comment: Hi @DannySchoemann. Can you provide a source for that? AFAIK, few shuls are following that halacha. As a matter of fact, the prayer includes a phrase added on Shabbat *Shabbat hi miliz'ok..*

Comment: @DannySchoemann deoraisas or derabbanans?

Comment: @DanF Indeed few shuls follow the halakha (probably because some people just show up to pray for sick people; sad). The phrase _Refuah Kerova Lavo_ is not an addition to the regular prayer but a replacement prayer. On Shabbat we can't pray directly "Please heal these people" unless there's risk of life but rather we pray obliquely "healing comes soon". Sticking an oblique prayer in after saying the direct prayer anyway (as some Siddurim do) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Heshy Deoraisas. It's actually a Machloket Rishonim if even that is permitted. Some also hold you can only pray for a person in Pikuach Nefesh if they are in the city there so you know they haven't died yet, but if they are in a different city where you won't hear yet if they died, then you can't pray for them since maybe they died already. (Generally speaking Ashkenazi Rishonim are stricter than Sefardic Rishonim. See this article for the full treatment http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53907&st=&pgnum=178)

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for the info. In my shul, what's even worse is that we (rather, I, as I'm the gabbai who says the prayer most of the time) are praying for people who have either recovered or who have died. The rabbi frequently gets a call from a shul member who gives a name, but the member rarely attends shul. The name can be on the list for months, and no one follows up on the status. We do delete most names after a month, anyway, unless someone asks to renew.

Comment: @DanF - Kitzur SA סימן קצב - דין החולה והרופא - in 192:2 says so: גַּם נוֹהֲגִין לְבָרֵךְ אֶת הַחוֹלִים בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת. וְאִם הוּא מְסֻכָּן, מְבָרְכִין אוֹתוֹ אֲפִלּוּ בְּשַׁבָּת וְיוֹם טוֹב

Comment: @Heshy - I assume it because of וְדַבֵּר דָּבָר - so what does that make it? And what's the difference?

Comment: @DanF - As DoubleAA says. See Kitzur SA סימן קצג - הלכות בקור חולים in 193:4 that one replaces the usual prayer with וּבַשַׁבָּת יֹאמַר, "שַׁבָּת הִיא מִלִּזְעֹק, וּרְפוּאָה קְרוֹבָה לָבוֹא, וְרַחֲמָיו מְרֻבִּים, וְשִׁבְתוּ בְּשָלוֹם " - adding it in at the end is the classic "Nicht auf Shabbes geredt" - "oops, I shouldn't have said that on Shabbes". (And our Gabai always ends the list with ואת כל החולים בתוך שאר חולי ישראל" - "and all other ill people - amongst all the ill ones". Just because it's done by everybody doesn't make it right.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I meant: can you pray for him if you can violate derabbanans on his behalf, or only if it's actual pikuach nefesh and you can violate deoraisas?  DoubleAA answered already.