# What does מצלאים mean? What was said?

Tags: history, translation

In [O"C 288:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.288.10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) the Shulchan Aruch states:

> נרדף מפני רוח רעה שאמרו לאו דוקא דה"ה לכל חולי שיש בו סכנת היום זועקים ומתחננין וכן נהגו לומר **מצלאים** בשבת על חולים המסוכנים סכנות היום:‏
>  הגה וכן מותר לברך החולה המסוכן בו ביום. (ליקוטי מהר"י ברין וב"י בשם הר"ן פרק ג' דתענית):‏

Not only may one pray for somebody - on Shabbat - who has a Ruach Ra'ah, but also for anybody with a life-threatening condition, and thus we have the custom to say **מצלאים** on Shabbat for deathly ill patients.

I have never heard of מצלאים and I don't even know how to pronounce it. Any ideas what it is?

(Or: מצלאים is clearly something they said - anybody have a Nussach?)

Comment: check out the bottom of page 13 https://www.academia.edu/40181285/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA or get this book https://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F.html?id=5rIrswEACAAJ

Comment: @rosends - that's the info I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88881/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Prisha to Tur Orach Chaim 288:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Prisha%2C_Orach_Chaim.288.14.1?lang=bi) explains:

> פי' מצלאין נוסח של ברכות הלועזים לחולים מתחיל מצלנא אנחנא כמו שמתחיל שלנו מי שבירך כו'‏
>
> *Matzla'in* means a version of a foreign [Aramaic] blessing for sick people which begins *maztlana anachna* (we pray), analagous to how our prayers begin *mi sheberach* (He Who blessed).

For a version of this prayer, see [Kol Bo 240](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%95/%D7%A7%D7%9E) (hat-tip to b a and rosends).